# How to recalculate values row by row in pandas data frame when multiple groupby() and shift() is necessary?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe. There is a column in it - `Shares` - that should be calculated row by row, based on `Equity` column values from previous index.

I tried to play around with defining a function to be able to `apply()` to the data frame row by row, but I realized I cannot use neither `groupby()` nor `shift()` with this method.

I created the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date_index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', end='1/10/2019')
symbol_index = ['AAPL','BOA','GE','MSFT']

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([date_index, symbol_index], names=['Date', 'Symbol'])
col = ['Price', 'Shares', 'Profit','Total_Profit', 'Equity']

data = pd.DataFrame(index=idx,columns=col)

price_list = [46, 17, 56, 66, 54, 79, 33, 63, 60, 63, 39, 26]
data['Price'] = price_list
```

My initial dataframe looks like this:

```
                   Price  Shares  Profit  Total_Profit   Equity
Date       Symbol                                              
2019-01-01 AAPL       46   NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
           BOA        17   NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
           GE         56   NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
           MSFT       66   NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
2019-01-02 AAPL       54   NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
           BOA        79   NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
           GE         33   NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
           MSFT       63   NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
2019-01-03 AAPL       60   NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
           BOA        63   NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
           GE         39   NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
           MSFT       26   NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
```

I need these variables:

```
starting_capital = 5000
risk_per_position = 0.1
```

And I defined the columns:

```
data['Shares'] = data.groupby('Symbol')['Equity'].shift(1).fillna(starting_capital) * risk_per_position / data['Price']
data['Shares'] = round(data['Shares'],0)
data['Profit'] = data['Shares'] * data['Price']
data['Total_Profit'] = data.groupby(by=['Date','Symbol'])['Profit'].sum().groupby('Date').cumsum().groupby('Date').tail(1).cumsum()
data['Total_Profit'] = data['Total_Profit'].bfill()
data['Equity'] = starting_capital + data['Total_Profit']
data['previous equity'] = data.groupby('Symbol')['Equity'].shift(1).fillna(starting_capital)
```

`Shares` at `date_index` - and consequently `Profit`, `Total_Profit` and `Equity` as well - should be calculated based on `Equity` value at `previous_date_index`. However, it is now always calculated based on `starting_capital` and the output is:

```
                   Price  Shares  Profit  Total_Profit   Equity
Date       Symbol                                              
2019-01-01 AAPL       46    11.0   506.0        2031.0   7031.0
           BOA        17    29.0   493.0        2031.0   7031.0
           GE         56     9.0   504.0        2031.0   7031.0
           MSFT       66     8.0   528.0        2031.0   7031.0
2019-01-02 AAPL       54     9.0   486.0        3990.0   8990.0
           BOA        79     6.0   474.0        3990.0   8990.0
           GE         33    15.0   495.0        3990.0   8990.0
           MSFT       63     8.0   504.0        3990.0   8990.0
2019-01-03 AAPL       60     8.0   480.0        5975.0  10975.0
           BOA        63     8.0   504.0        5975.0  10975.0
           GE         39    13.0   507.0        5975.0  10975.0
           MSFT       26    19.0   494.0        5975.0  10975.0
```

And the output should be:

```
                   Price  Shares  Profit  Total_Profit   Equity
Date       Symbol                                              
2019-01-01 AAPL       46    11.0   506.0        2031.0   7031.0
           BOA        17    29.0   493.0        2031.0   7031.0
           GE         56     9.0   504.0        2031.0   7031.0
           MSFT       66     8.0   528.0        2031.0   7031.0
2019-01-02 AAPL       54    13.0   702.0        4830.0   9830.0
           BOA        79     9.0   711.0        4830.0   9830.0
           GE         33    21.0   693.0        4830.0   9830.0
           MSFT       63    11.0   693.0        4830.0   9830.0
2019-01-03 AAPL       60    16.0   960.0        8761.0  13761.0
           BOA        63    16.0  1008.0        8761.0  13761.0
           GE         39    25.0   975.0        8761.0  13761.0
           MSFT       26    38.0   988.0        8761.0  13761.0
```

I would appreciate your help. What is the correct formula for column `Shares` in this case?

Comment: could you show your initial dataframe..its easier to understand what you want from inital DF to final DF than read the coding..,

Comment: I forgot to include the definition of `Price` column, I just added that one as well.

Comment: its ok..i understand what you want now...

Comment: I think I have a solution, I will post it and you might check that.

Answer (score 0):

```
data['Shares'] = data.['Equity'].shift(-1).groupby('Symbol').fillna(starting_capital) * 
risk_per_position / data['Price']
```

Try shifting shifting `'Equity'` column by -1 and then performing group by.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question. This will do the trick:

```
def portfolio_calc(row):

    global starting_capital

    row['Shares'] = starting_capital * risk_per_position / row['Price']
    row['Shares'] = round(row['Shares'].astype(float), 0)
    row['Profit'] = row['Shares'] * row['Price']
    row['Total_Profit'] = row['Profit'].sum()
    row['Equity'] = starting_capital + row['Total_Profit']
    starting_capital += row['Profit'].sum()

    return row

data = data.groupby('Date').apply(portfolio_calc)
```

The only difference we have here is that the output at `Total_Profit` will include the sum of `Profit` for the given date but not the cumulative sum of `Profit`s for all dates.